# Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) when loading dyplyr and tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, namespaces, tidyverse

I am new to R. I am using version 4.0.2 (windows) and it was working well until I tried to use "dplyr" and "tidyverse" packages. I am able to download both packages but when I try to load them I get the error below. I have tried reinstalling R and Rstudio, I have tried update.packages() and then restarted Rstudio but still I get this error. If I try require(dplyr), then I still this error.

Can anyone please help me?

`> library(dplyr) Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in namespaceExport(ns, exports): undefined exports: as_glue, backtick, double_quote, glue, glue_col, glue_collapse, glue_data, glue_data_col, glue_data_safe, glue_data_sql, glue_safe, glue_sql, identity_transformer, single_quote, trim In addition: Warning message: S3 methods ‘+.glue’, ‘[.glue’, ‘[[.glue’, ‘as.character.glue’, ‘as_glue.character’, ‘as_glue.default’, ‘as_glue.glue’, ‘print.glue’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found`

Answer (score 0):

This became too long for a comment, but it might be because the library `dplyr` is part of the `tidyverse` library. `tidyverse` is much bigger, and includes a bunch of different libraries/packages https://www.tidyverse.org/packages/

Do you still get the error if you load `dplyr` without `tidyverse`? In other words does the error only come when you load the second package, regardless of which is the second? It might be telling you that it can't load the package twice, but I am not sure, I haven't seen this specific error message.

Comment: I get this error even if I try to load dplyr alone.

Comment: hmm, I have the same R version (also windows) and don't have the issue with dplyr 1.0.0 or 1.0.2 (just updated). Have you tried deleting the packages completely from your machine, and then installing (rather than updating)?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share that I managed to fix this problem. I realised that the folder where the packages were being stored was being backed up in OneDrive, ie. OneDrive was in the file pathway. So I unlinked my OneDrive, re-installed R, Rtools & Rstudio and then both dplyer and tidyverse started working for me. I don't know why I didn't have that error with other packages but this seems to have fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the issue was, specifically, that the 'digest' package was stored into my OneDrive. The issue was solved (after three days of struggle) when I created a local library (`~/local-lib`) for the package that required ggplot2 (called, "factoextra").

```
install.packages("ggplot2", lib = "C:/Users/MY_USER_NAME/R/local-lib")
library("ggplot2",lib = "C:/Users/MY_USER_NAME/R/local-lib")

install.packages("digest", lib = "C:/Users/MY_USER_NAME/R/local-lib")
library("digest",lib = "C:/Users/MY_USER_NAME/R/local-lib")

install.packages("factoextra", lib = "C:/Users/MY_USER_NAME/R/local-lib")
library("factoextra",lib = "C:/Users/MY_USER_NAME/R/local-lib")
```

Another more permanent solution is published [here](https://www.accelebrate.com/library/how-to-articles/r-rstudio-library), but I only have limited administrative rights to my computer, so I couldn't pull this one off. If you are hampered by admin rights, you can potentially run your R environment in [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), which also isn't a perfect solution, but for those of us in universities with stringent IT departments, that seems to work alright.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the `civis` package and determined that installing the `roxygen2` package first would allow the `civis` installation to complete. It still gave a bunch of namespace warnings, and I'm having to call civis functions using the `civis::` prefix, but other than that it seems to work.

I doubt this is the only cause of this kind of error, but if you're having problems it might be worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (tough with different packages). Installing rdpack which included the first undefined export (append_to_Rd_list, in my case) solved it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).